# How to use Docker FFMPEG and HLS on my website

Tags: ffmpeg, docker, web, codec, hls

I want to use a Docker container to convert an mkv video to an HLS "video". This is my command for it:

```
docker run --rm \
  -v /mnt:/config \
  linuxserver/ffmpeg \
  -i "/config/test.mkv" \
  -c:v copy \
  -c:a copy \
  -sn \
  -f hls \
  -hls_list_size 0 \
  /config/hls/output.m3u8
```

when i run this command everything is created correctly, with VLC i can use the m3u8 file only Video.js says "The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported". I have also set the audio codec and video codec to AAC and 264 for testing but it didn't work any better. Ich nutze Video.js und wenn ich auf einem anderen Rechner wo ich kein docker nutzen muss geht m3u8 im web aber nicht bei vlc mit diesem befehl.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v h264 -master_pl_name master.m3u8 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls -map 0 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -strict -2 -vf "subtitles=input.mkv" -map a -map v -map s -var_stream_map "a:0,v:0,s:0 a:1,v:1 s:1" test/stream_%v.m3u8
```

you don't need to care about the directories i changed them

Comment: Hello, please use English only. Also, this is lacking any details, like what sstem is the Docker container running and how exactly is ffmpeg installed there?